# Can't check SMART data on SSD?

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive, ssd, disk, smart

I'm trying to check SMART data. I have `Ubuntu 18.04` installed on `Kingston A1000, M.2 - 480GB` SSD.

I can check all other disks but this.

[image]
[image]

```
milano@milano-PC:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/nvme0n1p1

/dev/nvme0n1p1:
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Do you know how to check it?

Comment: Apparently  it doesn't support SMART. Check for a firmware update for the SSD.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since SSD drives are designed to use completely different parameters than HDDs, most SMART utilities do not report SSD data correctly.  The `smartmontools` package for Linux contains a utility to scan for SSDs which will report drive health.

Install the smartmontools package from the command line:

```
sudo apt install smartmontools
```

Then use the `smartctl` tool with the following command where X is the letter of the SSD you want to test (in your case it would be `/dev/nvme0n1p1` instead of `/dev/sdX`):

```
sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdX
```

You can a short test on the SSD with this command:

```
sudo smartctl -t short -a /dev/sdX
```

Or also a long test with this command:

```
sudo smartctl -t long -a /dev/sdX
```