# Ubuntu running terribly slow (no memory or CPU issues)

Tags: boot, kubuntu, ram, cpu

I have a new laptop on which I dual booted Windows 10 and Kubuntu 18.04. Everything worked out fine for the last few days however yesterday and today my Kubuntu is very laggy and extremely slow.

**No memory or CPU issues** 
I have checked `top` but no abnormalities there, both CPU and memory stayed below 5%. I rebooted my laptop and even for the login screen to show up takes extremely long. I also checked `iotop` but no processes seem to be busy writing or reading.

**Enough space**

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8072692     2261004     1325488      137504     4486200     5381164
Swap:       7812092         768     7811324
```

**System must be easily capable of handling ubuntu, as it did the past few days**

*Cpu info*

```
    Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              8
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               142
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
Stepping:            10
CPU MHz:             800.000
CPU max MHz:         1600,0000
CPU min MHz:         400,0000
BogoMIPS:            3600.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-7
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d
```

*Memory info*

```
MemTotal:        8072692 kB
MemFree:         1067644 kB
MemAvailable:    5165636 kB
Buffers:           94312 kB
Cached:          4350420 kB
SwapCached:           88 kB
Active:          2910268 kB
Inactive:        3677080 kB
Active(anon):    2040920 kB
Inactive(anon):   294884 kB
Active(file):     869348 kB
Inactive(file):  3382196 kB
Unevictable:          32 kB
Mlocked:              32 kB
SwapTotal:       7812092 kB
SwapFree:        7811324 kB
Dirty:            506280 kB
Writeback:          1052 kB
AnonPages:       2142736 kB
Mapped:          3351496 kB
Shmem:            193192 kB
Slab:             254680 kB
SReclaimable:     141592 kB
SUnreclaim:       113088 kB
KernelStack:        9088 kB
PageTables:        30456 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    11848436 kB
Committed_AS:    4448964 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      240244 kB
DirectMap2M:     5957632 kB
DirectMap1G:     2097152 kB
```

**Startup services**

```
UNIT                                                  LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION                                                       
accounts-daemon.service                               loaded active running Accounts Service                                                  
acpid.service                                         loaded active running ACPI event daemon                                                 
apparmor.service                                      loaded active exited  AppArmor initialization                                           
apport.service                                        loaded active exited  LSB: automatic crash report generation                            
avahi-daemon.service                                  loaded active running Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack                                           
bluetooth.service                                     loaded active running Bluetooth service                                                 
clean-mount-point@media-rick-TOSHIBA\x20EXT.service   loaded active running Clean the /media/rick/TOSHIBA EXT mount point                     
console-setup.service                                 loaded active exited  Set console font and keymap                                       
cron.service                                          loaded active running Regular background program processing daemon                      
cups-browsed.service                                  loaded active running Make remote CUPS printers available locally                       
cups.service                                          loaded active running CUPS Scheduler                                                    
dbus.service                                          loaded active running D-Bus System Message Bus                                          
grub-common.service                                   loaded active exited  LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB                              
haveged.service                                       loaded active running Entropy daemon using the HAVEGE algorithm                         
irqbalance.service                                    loaded active running irqbalance daemon                                                 
kerneloops.service                                    loaded active running Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures  
keyboard-setup.service                                loaded active exited  Set the console keyboard layout                                   
kmod-static-nodes.service                             loaded active exited  Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel
ModemManager.service                                  loaded active running Modem Manager                                                     
mpd.service                                           loaded active running Music Player Daemon                                               
networkd-dispatcher.service                           loaded active running Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd                            
NetworkManager-wait-online.service                    loaded active exited  Network Manager Wait Online                                       
NetworkManager.service                                loaded active running Network Manager                                                   
packagekit.service                                    loaded active running PackageKit Daemon                                                 
polkit.service                                        loaded active running Authorization Manager                                             
rsyslog.service                                       loaded active running System Logging Service                                            
rtkit-daemon.service                                  loaded active running RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service                             
sddm.service                                          loaded active running Simple Desktop Display Manager                                    
setvtrgb.service                                      loaded active exited  Set console scheme                                                
snapd.seeded.service                                  loaded active exited  Wait until snapd is fully seeded                                  
systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service   loaded active exited  Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight
systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-FE67\x2d3101.service loaded active exited  File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/FE67-3101                  
systemd-journal-flush.service                         loaded active exited  Flush Journal to Persistent Storage                               
systemd-journald.service                              loaded active running Journal Service                                                   
systemd-logind.service                                loaded active running Login Service                                                     
systemd-modules-load.service                          loaded active exited  Load Kernel Modules                                               
systemd-random-seed.service                           loaded active exited  Load/Save Random Seed                                             
systemd-remount-fs.service                            loaded active exited  Remount Root and Kernel File Systems                              
systemd-resolved.service                              loaded active running Network Name Resolution                                           
systemd-sysctl.service                                loaded active exited  Apply Kernel Variables                                            
systemd-sysusers.service                              loaded active exited  Create System Users                                               
systemd-timesyncd.service                             loaded active running Network Time Synchronization                                      
systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                    loaded active exited  Create Static Device Nodes in /dev                                
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                        loaded active exited  Create Volatile Files and Directories                             
systemd-udev-trigger.service                          loaded active exited  udev Coldplug all Devices                                         
systemd-udevd.service                                 loaded active running udev Kernel Device Manager                                        
systemd-update-utmp.service                           loaded active exited  Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown                            
systemd-user-sessions.service                         loaded active exited  Permit User Sessions                                              
thermald.service                                      loaded active running Thermal Daemon Service                                            
udisks2.service                                       loaded active running Disk Manager                                                      
ufw.service                                           loaded active exited  Uncomplicated firewall                                            
upower.service                                        loaded active running Daemon for power management                                       
user-runtime-dir@1000.service                         loaded active exited  /run/user/1000 mount wrapper                                      
user@1000.service                                     loaded active running User Manager for UID 1000                                         
whoopsie.service                                      loaded active running crash report submission daemon                                    
wpa_supplicant.service                                loaded active running WPA supplicant
```

---

---

To summarize, my Kubuntu is slow directly after booting (login background appears but for the password field to show up takes long already). I haven't found any processes that excessively consume CPU or memory. Now I really have no idea what I should do..

---

**Reactions to comments**

**SMART results for 1TB HDD disk**
[image]

---

**Firware and bios** 
My laptop: Lenovo ideapad 330

*Bios*: 8TCN25WW

*Firmware SSD*:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    0 443,1G  0 part 
└─sda3        8:3    0 488,3G  0 part /
sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
nvme0n1     259:0    0 119,2G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  88,7G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0  1000M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0   7,5G  0 part [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p6 259:6    0  21,9G  0 part
```

I looked at the nvme0n1p6, with `sudo smartctl -i /dev/nvme0n1p6`, giving me:

```
Model Number:                       KBG30ZMT128G TOSHIBA
Serial Number:                      18JPA1SDP1TP
Firmware Version:                   0105ADLA
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x1179
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x00080d
Controller ID:                      0
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          128,035,676,160 [128 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
```

Comment: Edit your question to include a screenshot of the `Disks` app SMART Data, and I'll take a look for you. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Thankyou for responding! I wasn't home yet but now I'am I have downloaded Disks (see edit) but I cannot find SMART?

Comment: Hello! Once you've started the `Disks` application, go to the "hamburger" icon at the top-right corner, and select `SMART Data & Tests`. Do that for each disk that you see in the left pane, then screenshot each of the SMART Data windows, and edit those into your question for me to take a look.

Comment: The 128G is SSD, yes? Is one of your 1T HDD internal, and one external? What's on the external drive(s)?

Comment: What make/model laptop? How old? Does Windows run OK, or slow?

Answer (score 1):

You may have a problem with your hard disk.

**Check your HDD SMART Data...**

Start the `Disks` app and review the SMART Data. Do NOT assume that just because it says `OK` that there isn't really a problem. Let me view a screenshot.

**Lets check your file system...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Then lets check for bad blocks...**

```
Note: do NOT perform this on a SSD

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: backup your important files FIRST!
```

`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f     Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c     This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
          read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
          If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
          inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
          tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
          scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k     When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
          bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
          running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
          list.

   -y     Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
          used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
          same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Comment: When I boot from my usb and click on `try kubuntu` is wont load either.

Comment: Thankyou there was a bad block!

Comment: @CodeNoob please give me more details. One of the 1T drives? Internal or external?

Comment: @CodeNoob still having a problem?

Comment: I eventually reinstalled my kubuntu and it worked fine for a day but now it slows down again till the same degree as where I was yesterday morning. I cannot run `SMART` because my windows and ubuntu are installed on an SSD drive

Comment: @CodeNoob Why can't you run SMART? We never did fully accomplish that before, and it would be very instructive for me to see so I can help you further. There are a few questions that you never did answer also. Why did you feel it necessary to reinstall kubuntu? Wasn't it working well after the bad blocking?

Comment: I don't know why I cannot run SMART, it's grayed out when I select my 128GB SSD however I can run it for my 1TB HDD (see results in my edit). To address your second question, in my search to fix the problem I disabled and enabled quite some things so the make sure my installation was fully functional I decided to re-install it.

Comment: @CodeNoob you only gave me SMART Data for one 1T drive... don't you have two? The problem is very evident there. Read/seek/command-timeout errors. I wonder if your other disk shows the same. You may have to update your BIOS. `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` then go to the manufacturor's web site and check for a newer version. You also need to check for a firmware update for the SSD.

Comment: Apprecciate your help! The problem is I cannot run SMART for my SSD (my second drive having linux & windows installed on it) I dont know why I can't. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128525/cant-check-smart-data-on-ssd i saw you commented there as well hahha i will check for the update

Comment: Ok I can't run a thing anymore it's getting too slow. I tried to boot from a bootable USB but this is extemely slow as well (waited for like 20 minutes after clicking on "try kubuntu" but nothing happened). No idea what I should do now? Btw windows works fine

Comment: @CodeNoob what else do you have connected to this computer? Do you have a second 1T HDD, and is it external? Remove all external devices and see if you can get the dmidecode command to respond. Then continue to check for BIOS updates, and SSD firmware updates. Report back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94306/discussion-between-codenoob-and-heynnema).